# Error setting up Mule proxy api to use a domain shared listener

Tags: ssl, mule, mulesoft, anypoint-platform

I created a mule api proxy to publish an internal api. The Api proxy should use a shared listener for https protocol.
When i start the api proxy i get the following error from mule engine:

```
+ org.mule.runtime.deployment.model.api.DeploymentInitException:               +
+ PropertyNotFoundException: Couldn't find configuration property value for    +
+ key ${inbound.keystore.password} from properties provider environment        +
+ properties provider - within resolver Deployment properties trying to        +
+ process key inbound.keystore.password - within resolver global-properties    +
+ configuration attributes trying to process key inbound.keystore.password -   +
+ within resolver environment properties provider trying to process key        +
+ inbound.keystore.password - within resolver Deployment properties trying to  +
+ process key inbound.keystore.password - within resolver                      +
+ configuration-attribute provider composed of (<configuration-properties      +
+ file="config.properties"> - file: http-proxy.xml, line number: 16) trying    +
+ to process key inbound.keystore.password - within resolver                   +
+ global-properties configuration attributes trying to process key             +
+ inbound.keystore.password - within resolver configuration-attribute          +
+ provider composed of (<configuration-properties file="config.properties"> -  +
+ file: http-proxy.xml, line number: 16) trying to process key                 +
+ inbound.keystore.password - within resolver environment properties provider  +
+ trying to process key inbound.keystore.password - within resolver            +
+ Deployment properties trying to process key inbound.keystore.password -      +
+ within resolver External files trying to process key                         +
+ inbound.keystore.password - within resolver Deployment properties trying to  +
+ process key inbound.keystore.password
```

I can't find either `config.properties` or `http-proxy.xml` in `conf` folder. The shared port is successful used by a mule application that refers the domain that shares it.
Off course, the domain project is already published in the server.

Any clues?

**Update**

Domain config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<domain:mule-domain
        xmlns:tls="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls"
        xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
        xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
        xmlns:domain="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xsi:schemaLocation="
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
               http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/domain/current/mule-domain-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/tls/current/mule-tls.xsd">
    <tls:context name="Domain_TLS_Context" doc:name="TLS Context" doc:id="some guid" >
        <tls:key-store type="pkcs12" path="mule.p12" keyPassword="***" password="***"/>
    </tls:context>
    <http:listener-config name="myShared1_Listener_config" doc:name="api.payshop.pt_Listener_config" doc:id="50d5570d-5491-4617-a8e6-caa699dbbcc6" >
        <http:listener-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="0.0.0.0" port="9443" tlsContext="Domain_TLS_Context" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <http:listener-config name="myShared2_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="3e9c63c5-2f37-41fb-8743-c27bcf589b38" >
        <http:listener-connection protocol="HTTPS" host="0.0.0.0" port="9444" tlsContext="Domain_TLS_Context" />
    </http:listener-config>
    <!-- configure here resource to be shared within the domain -->
</domain:mule-domain>
```

The proxy Api:

As an proxy api it's not a configuration file. The settings used at the Api Manager page are the following:

```
Downstream:
    Protocol: HTTPS
    Inbound TLS: Not defined (its defined in the domain project)
    Port: 9444
    Base Path:/test
    ... the rest has the defaults
```

Comment: Please share the flow and configs from both the proxy application and domain. And properties files, with confidential values masked of course.

Comment: I just add what you ask for.

Comment: There is not enough to troubleshoot. Maybe the proxy is not using the TLS configuration from the domain? Check http-proxy.xml in the proxy app. It will not be in the conf folder.

Comment: I bump into this [official page](https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/proxy-domain-support)
I don't think the domain was created with this template. I'm going to try create a new one.

Comment: That was the problem. Its working now.